# Is there an equivalent to moment timezone with a Javascript date?

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs, moment-timezone

I have this method below that takes in a Javascript date and then has to use Moment js to do its timezone conversion.

**QUESTION** - Is there a way to accomplish this without moment, just using a JS Date?

```js
// ex. (someDate, 'America/Los_Angeles', 'MMM DD @ h:mm A z')

transform(dateUtc: Date, timeZone: string, momentFormat: string): string {
  const tempDateUtc = moment(dateUtc).utc(true);
  tempDateUtc.tz(timeZone);
  return tempDateUtc.format(momentFormat);
}
```

Comment: You *just* want the `.tz()` right?

Comment: You can do it with [*Intl.DateTimeFormat*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat) and the *timezone* option plus *timeZoneName* set to *longOffset*.

Answer (score 0):

To apply specific date formatting, rather than a locale based format, then no, not really, but it is possible to get the localized date parts to create a custom format.

As @RobG mentioned, you can use the [Intl.DateTimeFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat) to create a formatter. You build your [options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat), including your timezone, and then use it's [formatToParts(date)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/formatToParts) method to get the parts you need to construct your output.

Of course, this only works well if your `Date` is constructed using an epoch or UTC value.